# Remove nodes in xml based on sub-node value

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I'm working with a wordpress xml dump, and for whatever reason, wordpress has exported every user in our database as an "author" of each post. In order to make the xml file easier to work with, I would like to remove all of the author nodes except for one.

Here's an example of what I have:

```
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/">
<wp:author>
    <wp:author_id>35622</wp:author_id>
    <wp:author_login>some_username_1</wp:author_login>
    <wp:author_email>email@address.com</wp:author_email>
    <wp:author_display_name><![CDATA[some_username_1]]></wp:author_display_name>
    <wp:author_first_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_first_name>
    <wp:author_last_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_last_name>
</wp:author>
<wp:author>
    <wp:author_id>35290</wp:author_id>
    <wp:author_login>my_unique_username</wp:author_login>
    <wp:author_email>email@address.com</wp:author_email>
    <wp:author_display_name><![CDATA[my_unique_username]]></wp:author_display_name>
    <wp:author_first_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_first_name>
    <wp:author_last_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_last_name>
</wp:author>
<wp:author>
    <wp:author_id>35289</wp:author_id>
    <wp:author_login>some_username_2</wp:author_login>
    <wp:author_email>email@address.com</wp:author_email>
    <wp:author_display_name><![CDATA[some_username_2]]></wp:author_display_name>
    <wp:author_first_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_first_name>
    <wp:author_last_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_last_name>
</wp:author>
<wp:author>
    <wp:author_id>33404</wp:author_id>
    <wp:author_login>some_username_3</wp:author_login>
    <wp:author_email>email@address.com</wp:author_email>
    <wp:author_display_name><![CDATA[some_username_3]]></wp:author_display_name>
    <wp:author_first_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_first_name>
    <wp:author_last_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_last_name>
</wp:author>
```

Times a few thousand more entries

I would like to remove all of the  nodes except for this one:

```
<wp:author>
    <wp:author_id>35290</wp:author_id>
    <wp:author_login>my_unique_username</wp:author_login>
    <wp:author_email>email@address.com</wp:author_email>
    <wp:author_display_name><![CDATA[my_unique_username]]></wp:author_display_name>
    <wp:author_first_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_first_name>
    <wp:author_last_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_last_name>
</wp:author>
```

Attempting to do this in a shell script but I'm not really sure where to start as I've never used xmlstarlet before so would appreciate any help.

Updated to reflect data root and solution that I found:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//wp:author[wp:author_id != '35290']" file.xml > out.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is as follows:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "//wp:author[wp:author_id != '35290']" file.xml > out.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking just a snippet out of an XML file doesn't really give us enough to provide a complete answer. I wrapped this sample data in a root tag:

```
<root xmlns:wp="some.url">
...
</root
```

Then you can provide an XPath expression to find the node you're looking for: all "wp:author" nodes that contain a "wp:author_id" child with the specific value.

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//wp:author[wp:author_id = "35289"]' file.xml
<wp:author xmlns:wp="some.url">
    <wp:author_id>35289</wp:author_id>
    <wp:author_login>some_username_2</wp:author_login>
    <wp:author_email>email@address.com</wp:author_email>
    <wp:author_display_name>some_username_2</wp:author_display_name>
    <wp:author_first_name></wp:author_first_name>
    <wp:author_last_name></wp:author_last_name>
</wp:author>
```

I've found [this page of XPath examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-Skvdq3Bt4_C_UWxanVCi2g&epi=TnL5HPStwNw-Skvdq3Bt4_C_UWxanVCi2g&irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=(ir__g2ci6zhvyskfr1l0xkrizr11j32xhdmt3t3w003n00)(7593)(1243925)(TnL5HPStwNw-Skvdq3Bt4_C_UWxanVCi2g)()&irclickid=_g2ci6zhvyskfr1l0xkrizr11j32xhdmt3t3w003n00) helpful

Comment: My apologies, I'm only adept enough at xml to work with it in php. The correct data root is: `<rss version="2.0" xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/">`

Comment: I did eventually find what I was looking for, which is very similar to the example you gave: `xmlstarlet ed -d "/rss/channel/wp:author[wp:author_id != '35289']" file.xml > file2.xml`

Comment: Good one: that will keep all the enclosing XML tags which my answer does not. I recommend you provide an answer to your own question and then accept it. That will guide future readers to the correct solution.